# How to replace some words in a text with another word

Tags: python, str-replace

I am trying to replace a word i.e "sound system" with "sound_sytem" in python using dictionary. However it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
dictionary = {'audio system': 'audio_system'}
def replace_word(text):
  return " ".join([dictionary.get(w,w) for w in text.split()])

text = "adding a little more to an audio system,improve the audio system to be better"

print(replace_word(text))
```

here is my output :

```
adding a little more to an audio system,improve the audio system to be better
```

Comment: This is not working because `split()` splits on every space, so that you don't get a string `audio system` but separate strings `audio` and `system`. For a working solution see below.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `replace()`:

```
for i in dictionary:
    text.replace(i,dictionary[i])
```

this just replaces the key with value.
Your code doesn't work because, split function by default splits by space and `audio system` is split as `audio` and `system`.

---

Lets do this your way, using join:

```
dictionary = {'audio system': 'audio_system'}
def replace_word(text):
  return [dictionary[j].join([text.split(i) for i in dictionary][0]) for j in dictionary][0]

text = "adding a little more to an audio system,improve the audio system to be better"

print(replace_word(text))
```